# Why plugin gulp-google-cdn does not work?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, bower

Good day!

My question about gulpjs plugin gulp-google-cdn (i saw this plugin [here](http://bower.io/docs/tools/) and [here homepage](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-google-cdn)): does not replace my local JQuery in index.html for Google CDN URL.

File structure:

```
- /dist
- /src
-- /bower_components
-- index.html
- .bowerrc
- bower.json
- gulpfile.js
- package.json
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "template",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "normalize-css": "normalize.css#~3.0.3",
    "nodernizr-dev": "modernizr-dev#~3.1.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "jquery": {
      "main": "dist/jquery.min.js"
    },
    "normalize-css": {
      "main": "normalize.css"
    },
    "nodernizr-dev": {
      "main": "modernizr-latest.js"
    }
  }
}
```

.bowerrc

```
{
  "directory": "src/bower_components"
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "template",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-google-cdn": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var googlecdn = require('gulp-google-cdn');

gulp.task('cdn', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/index.html')
    .pipe(googlecdn(require('./bower.json'), {
      componentsPath: './src/bower_components/'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src'));
});
```

I try to write in index.html this

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this

```
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this

```
<script src="jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but task complete and URL does not replace.

Where is my bad?

Comment: You need to ensure the files are on a CDN that you are referring to.  You can specify additional CDNs with the options to find the files hosted on a server.